# Android Service that should run forever

Tags: android, service, broadcast

I have a printer that I'm connecting to it using the bluetooth. and I have a FileObserver that observes Downloads Folder and when and new pdf file created this observer notify me to print this new pdf .
How can I create a Service that run for forever ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the requirements and limitations of the Android OS it's really hard to implement something like "Service that run forever". But you can find some workaround for you exact task. Recommend you to read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) for more information.

I had a lot of situations when I needed "unstoppable" service, so I wrote my library. You can try it here: https://github.com/iardelian/Revive-S

Comment: Tnx https://stackoverflow.com/users/12072832/ivan-ardelian